# Can't get CSS to change class through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to learn web development, and I'm stuck on changing the CSS class through Javascript. I've looked at other websites and questions, but none of them are working for me, so I must be doing something stupid that I don't know about.

What I'm trying to get it to do is expand from the height 50 to 200 when I hover over. It doesn't do anything, however.

(I know I can do a :hover, but I need it to be in Javascript for other needs)

CSS:

```
.box{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;

    -webkit-transition: height 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 2s ease;
    -o-transition: height 2s ease;
    transition: height 2s ease;
}

.box-expand{
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/about.css">
    <script src="../javascript/preview_control.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];

box.onmouseover = function() {  
    box.toggleClass("box-expand");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're pretty close. `toggleClass()` is a jQuery function, `classList.toggle` is for vanilla JavaScript.

```
box.onmouseover = function() {  
  box.classList.toggle("box-expand");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. Is it something wrong with how I named the CSS class?

Comment: No your class is fine, I'm not sure why this wouldn't work. Perhaps it's because your <div class="box"> has no closing tag?

Answer (score 0):

hackNightly's answer works fine here... I added the missing closing tags...

```js
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];

box.onmouseover = function() {
  box.classList.toggle("box-expand");
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color:green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: height 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 2s ease;
  -o-transition: height 2s ease;
  transition: height 2s ease;
}
.box-expand {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/about.css">
  <script src="../javascript/preview_control.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with hackNightly's answer, and my box class seemed to be overriding the height with the 50px. Removing it fixed it.